# Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a new to Docker, and I'm trying to start a docker container on ubuntu with below commnad.

```
 docker-compose up -d
```

It ended up with the following error.

> ERROR: for testsigma_server  Cannot start service testsigma_server: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: permission denied
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7 # Replace with mysql:8.0.32 for m1
    platform: linux/x86_64 # Replace with linux/arm64/v8 for m1
    container_name: testsigma_mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testsigma_opensource
      LANG: C.UTF-8
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
    ports:
      - "3306"
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    healthcheck:
      test: out=$$(mysqladmin ping -h localhost -P 3306 -u root --password=root 2>&1); echo $$out | grep 'mysqld is alive' || { echo $$out; exit 1; }
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120
  testsigma_server:
    image: testsigmahq/server:v3.0.1 # Replace with testsigmahq/server:v3.0.1-m1 for m1
    container_name: testsigma_server
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./ts_data:/opt/app/ts_data
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
```

here is my yml

I'm trying to using another port to 442

but when I start server and try to browse the  to cannot access to web but can't not access.

Why it says the PORT is permission denied?

Comment: Are you running anything else on port 443? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: Yes, Nginx running on the server. but this docker setting export 443 to web console.
If install this server through docker will conflict with Nginix, so I decide to using another PC to install this container.